# How to set a Timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

How to set a Timeout function of 500 to this:

```
$('.menu ul li').on('click', function(){
   $(container).removeClass('menu-open');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.menu ul li').on('click', function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(container).removeClass( 'menu-open' );
    },500); // Time in ms
});
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 6):

You can use [jQuery delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$(container).delay(500).queue(function(){$(this).removeClass('menu-open').dequeue()});
```

Comment: `.delay` only adds a delay for functions that are added to the event queue. `removeClass` isn't a function that's added to the event queue. [It doesn't work.](http://jsfiddle.net/mxo0dwxw/)

Comment: With `.queue`, don't forget [`.dequeue`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/). It can cause headaches down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(container).removeClass( 'menu-open' );
}, 500);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is going on in your code, to help others.
How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something after 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

[jQuery setTimeout() Function Examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/)

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout(functionName.bind(this, i), 200);// 200 milliseconds